# ksoftware code-signing java crossplatform game

Tags: java, cross-platform, code-signing, leap-motion

I am currently developing a game for the leap motion controller in java. The application will be cross-plattform between osx and windows. I have searched a lot on code signing certificates and I finally found ksoftware which sell one year certificates for only 99$ is there anyone who have any experience of these? I would really appreciate some tips on wheter or note to choose them or maybe there are some other alternative thats even better.

Thanks //Simon Nilsson

Answer (score 0):

I hope I answered your questions via email well enough but if I didn't, please let me know. I'm happy to help with getting your files signed on both (or all 3) platforms.